# Scipy-optimize.root_scalar inconsistently gives f(a) and f(b) must have different signs

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am writing some code to fit one type of model ("macrospin model") to another type of model ("micromagnetic model"). The data from the micromagnetic model is generated from an open-source package called mumax and put into a pandas dataframe for access. The columns are labeled with an angle from 0 to 90 (the angle of the magnetic field in the simulation) and either "B" or "M" (for field and magnetization)

For each angle, I extract the B and the M columns for that particular simulation, extract the data corresponding to the positive B values, and use it as an input to the analytical macrospin model.

This is the part of the code in question:

```
def macrospin_angle(Ku, Kg, phi, Ms, B):
    #This calculates the angle of a macrospin in a field oriented phi degrees
    # This works for a single value of B
    theta0 = np.pi/2
    b = B*Ms/(2*Ku + 2*Kg*np.square(np.sin(phi)))
    f = lambda theta: np.sin(2*(theta-theta0)) + 2*b*np.sin(theta)
    return opt.root_scalar(f, bracket = [0, np.pi]).root

def fun(B_vals, Ku, Kg, phi, Ms):
    theta = np.zeros((len(B_vals),1))
    M = np.zeros((len(B_vals),1))
    for idx, current_B in enumerate(B):
        theta[idx] = macrospin_angle(Ku, Kg, phi, Ms, current_B)
        M[idx] = Ms*np.cos(theta[idx])
    return M


for angle in angles:    
    #First, extract the particular loop
    current_B = Full_Table[angle + "_B"]
    current_M = Full_Table[angle + "_M"]
    current_DT = pd.DataFrame()
    current_DT = pd.concat([current_DT, current_B, current_M], axis = 1)
    #Now extract the positive field range as two tables
    idx_max = np.argmax(current_DT[angle + "_B"].to_numpy())
    pos_DT_1 = current_DT[:idx_max]
    pos_DT_1 = pos_DT_1[pos_DT_1[angle + "_B"] > 0]
    pos_DT_2 = current_DT[idx_max:]
    pos_DT_2 = pos_DT_2[pos_DT_2[angle + "_B"] > 0]
    pos_DT_2 = pos_DT_2.iloc[::-1]
    #Average the two branches to get rid of hysteresis
    B_vals = 0.5*(pos_DT_1[angle + "_B"].to_numpy() + pos_DT_2[angle + "_B"].to_numpy())
    M_vals = 0.5*(pos_DT_1[angle + "_M"].to_numpy() + pos_DT_2[angle + "_M"].to_numpy())
    foo = fun(B_vals, 0.6E6, 0.06E6, 0, 1000e3)
```

The function "macrospin_angle" uses scipy.optimize.root_scalar to calculate a magnetization value for a particular value of the magnetic field. The function "fun" uses macrospin_angle to calculate a hysteresis loop. Eventually, I will use "fun" in a scipy least-squares fitting routine.

The problem that I am having is that root_scalar is telling me that two two endpoints f(a) and f(b) don't have different signs. When I look at the values of f(a) and f(b), however, they do have different signs. Even more strangely, if I just copy macrospin_angle and fun into their own script and use the B values from the pandas table directly, the script works just fine:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize as opt
def macrospin_angle(x, B):
    #This calculates the angle of a macrospin in a field oriented phi degrees
    # This works for a single value of B
    theta0 = np.pi/2
    b = B*x[3]/(2*x[0] + 2*x[1]*np.square(np.sin(x[2])))
    f = lambda theta: np.sin(2*(theta-theta0)) + 2*b*np.sin(theta)
    return opt.root_scalar(f, bracket = [0, np.pi]).root
B = [0.00999848, 0.02999543, 0.04999238, 0.06998934, 0.08998629,\
       0.10998324, 0.12998018, 0.14997715, 0.16997411, 0.18997107,\
       0.20996803, 0.22996497, 0.24996191, 0.26995886, 0.28995581,\
       0.30995279, 0.32994974, 0.34994669, 0.36994366, 0.38994062,\
       0.40993755, 0.4299345 , 0.44993147, 0.46992839, 0.48992537,\
       0.50992234, 0.52991928, 0.54991621, 0.56991315, 0.58991012,\
       0.60990707, 0.62990403, 0.64990101, 0.66989795, 0.6898949 ,\
       0.70989188, 0.72988883, 0.7498858 , 0.7698827 , 0.78987965,\
       0.8098767 , 0.8298736 , 0.8498705 , 0.8698675 , 0.88986445,\
       0.9098614 , 0.9298584 , 0.9498553 , 0.96985224, 0.98984927,\
       1.00984623, 1.0298432 , 1.04984005, 1.06983695, 1.08983395,\
       1.10983085, 1.12982785, 1.14982485, 1.16982175, 1.1898187 ,\
       1.2098157 , 1.22981265, 1.2498096 , 1.2698066 , 1.28980355,\
       1.3098005 , 1.3297975 , 1.3497944 , 1.3697913 , 1.3897883 ,\
       1.40978525, 1.4297822 , 1.4497792 , 1.46977615, 1.4897731 ]

x = [0.5e6, 0.05e6, 0, 1000e3]

theta = np.zeros((len(B),1))
m = np.zeros((len(B),1))
for idx, current_B in enumerate(B):
    theta[idx] = macrospin_angle(x,current_B)
    m[idx] = x[3]*np.cos(theta[idx])
plt.plot(B,m)
```

The above code works fine but is identical. I'm pretty lost so any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit of code that reproduces the error message, in particular with a few rows and colums of the `Full_Table` variable.

Answer (score 0):

In this function:

```
f = lambda theta: np.sin(2*(theta-theta0)) + 2*b*np.sin(theta)
```

The term `sin(2*(theta-theta0))` is periodic in theta, with period `pi`. Moreover, with the choice `theta0=np.pi/2`, the term has value 0 at `theta==0` and `theta=np.pi`. The term `2*b*np.sin(theta)` has value 0 at `theta==0` and `theta==np.pi` as well.

So, when you attempt to find the root within the bracket `[0, np.pi]`, tiny rounding errors can make the difference between getting a a suitable bracket or not. Your test values (the `B` array) are all with 8 decimals; the values that cause the error are probably different in less significant digits.

In any case, the choice of bracket is bad, because you could end up with the trivial solutions `theta=0` or `theta=np.pi`. You should set `bracket=[1e-9, np.pi-1e-9]` or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. After taking a couple days off I returned to the problem with fresh eyes and found a very weird solution. First of all, I tried implementing your suggestions and while they are definitely good practice they did not solve the problem. What finally ended up working is that after defining B_vals and M_vals I just made new variables B and M (by simply saying B = B_vals and M = M_vals). Passing B and M rather than B_vals and M_vals fixed the problem. I have no idea why it works, but it does!

Comment: Hmm, `B=B_vals` doesn't really do anything other than creating a name `B` that points to the same memory as `B_vals`. Just to be sure: I assume you are familiar with the concept of mutable variables?

Comment: Yes. I know it doesn't make any sense. However, if I run the script without that renaming it doesn't work and if I add it back it does.

Answer (score 0):

choice of [method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html) can matter, I suppose, & in [lib](https://gemfury.com/colesbury/python:scipy/-/content/optimize/zeros.py) itself there are examples... once I changed the method in params to `bracket=[0,1], method='bisect'` - I solved your problem in my own code, - in this way I solved such ValueError for my own task once...

Have tried for your code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize as opt
def macrospin_angle(x, B):
    #This calculates the angle of a macrospin in a field oriented phi degrees
    # This works for a single value of B
    theta0 = np.pi/2
    b = B*x[3]/(2*x[0] + 2*x[1]*np.square(np.sin(x[2])))
    f = lambda theta: np.sin(2*(theta-theta0)) + 2*b*np.sin(theta)
    return opt.root_scalar(f, bracket = [0, np.pi], method='bisect' ).root       # bracket = [0, np.pi], method='bisect'

B = [0.00999848, 0.02999543, 0.04999238, 0.06998934, 0.08998629,\
       0.10998324, 0.12998018, 0.14997715, 0.16997411, 0.18997107,\
       0.20996803, 0.22996497, 0.24996191, 0.26995886, 0.28995581,\
       0.30995279, 0.32994974, 0.34994669, 0.36994366, 0.38994062,\
       0.40993755, 0.4299345 , 0.44993147, 0.46992839, 0.48992537,\
       0.50992234, 0.52991928, 0.54991621, 0.56991315, 0.58991012,\
       0.60990707, 0.62990403, 0.64990101, 0.66989795, 0.6898949 ,\
       0.70989188, 0.72988883, 0.7498858 , 0.7698827 , 0.78987965,\
       0.8098767 , 0.8298736 , 0.8498705 , 0.8698675 , 0.88986445,\
       0.9098614 , 0.9298584 , 0.9498553 , 0.96985224, 0.98984927,\
       1.00984623, 1.0298432 , 1.04984005, 1.06983695, 1.08983395,\
       1.10983085, 1.12982785, 1.14982485, 1.16982175, 1.1898187 ,\
       1.2098157 , 1.22981265, 1.2498096 , 1.2698066 , 1.28980355,\
       1.3098005 , 1.3297975 , 1.3497944 , 1.3697913 , 1.3897883 ,\
       1.40978525, 1.4297822 , 1.4497792 , 1.46977615, 1.4897731 ]

x = [0.5e6, 0.05e6, 0, 1000e3]

theta = np.zeros((len(B),1))
m = np.zeros((len(B),1))
for idx, current_B in enumerate(B):
    theta[idx] = macrospin_angle(x,current_B)
    m[idx] = x[3]*np.cos(theta[idx])
plt.plot(B,m)
plt.show()
```

[image]